# User interaction in non-UI thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, backgroundworker

in my WPF - C# application, I have a time consuming function, which I execute with a BackgroundWorker. The job of this function is to add given data from a file into a database. Now and then, I need some user feedback, for example the data is already in the store and I want to ask the user, whether he wants to merge the data or create a new object or skip the data completely. Much like the dialog windows shows, if I try to copy a file to a location, where a file with the same name already exists.

The problem is, that I cannot call a GUI-window from a non GUI-thread. How could I implement this behavior?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Comment: Are you using WPF? Or, are you using WinForms?

Comment: I use WPF ... added this info to the question

Comment: Are you doing MVVM?  If so, then, you can design using INotifyPropertyChanged to get an event to the View from the ViewModel (or even the Model); I can provide or point you to an answer if you're using MVVM.

Comment: Most good solutions to this problem will involve using Dispatcher.Invoke or Dispatcher.BeginInvoke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the input of the answers here, I came to the following solution:

(Mis)Using the ReportProgress-method of the Backgroundworker in Combination with a EventWaitHandle. If I want to interact with the user, I call the ReportProgress-method and setting the background process on wait. In the Handler for the ReportProgress event I do the interaction and when finished, I release the EventWaitHandle.

```
    BackgroundWorker bgw;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bgw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgw_DoWork);
        bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bgw_RunWorkerCompleted);
        bgw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bgw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bgw_ProgressChanged);
    }

    // Starting the time consuming operation
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    // using the ProgressChanged-Handler to execute the user interaction
    void bgw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UserStateData usd = e.UserState as UserStateData;

        // UserStateData.Message is used to see **who** called the method
        if (usd.Message == "X")
        {
            // do the user interaction here
            UserInteraction wnd = new UserInteraction();
            wnd.ShowDialog();

            // A global variable to carry the information and the EventWaitHandle
            Controller.instance.TWS.Message = wnd.TextBox_Message.Text;
            Controller.instance.TWS.Background.Set();
        }
    }

    void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Result.ToString());
    }

    // our time consuming operation
    void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        // need 4 userinteraction: raise the ReportProgress event and Wait
        bgw.ReportProgress(0, new UserStateData() { Message = "X", Data = "Test" });
        Controller.instance.TWS.Background.WaitOne();

        // The WaitHandle was released, the needed information should be written to global variable
        string first = Controller.instance.TWS.Message.ToString();

        // ... and again
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        bgw.ReportProgress(0, new UserStateData() { Message = "X", Data = "Test" });
        Controller.instance.TWS.Background.WaitOne();

        e.Result = first + Controller.instance.TWS.Message;
    }
```

I hope I did not overlooked some critical issues. I'm not so familar with multithreading - maybe there should be some lock(object) somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You could work with EventWaitHandle ou AutoResetEvent, then whenever you want to prompt the user, you could the signal  UI, and then wait for the responde. The information about the file could be stored on a variable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I checked about TwoWaySignaling at http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx
As far as I understand it, the GUI thread is blocked with this method, because it waits for the Event from the thread in the background. But I do not want the GUI to block.

Comment: You could try to work with 3 threads: The GUI thread, the processing thread, and the listener thread. Then, when you begin yout method, the GUI would start the listener and the processing thread. The listener thread would wait for a signal from the processing thread, then, whenever signaled, it would invoke your confirmation method.

Comment: But the listener thread would not count as a GUI-thread and so would not be able to interact with the user, or am I wrong?

Comment: It doesn't need to, it will just interact with the GUI thread. Whenever a conflict occurs, invoke a method on your GUI thread to request orders from the user. I guess you'll probably need something like Dispatcher.Invoke

Answer (score 0):

If possible... my suggestion is to architect your long running task into atomic operations. Then you can create a queue of items accessible by both your background thread and UI thread.

```
public class WorkItem<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public Func<bool> Validate { get; set; }
    public Func<T, bool> Action { get; set; }
}
```

You can use something like this class. It uses a queue to manage the execution of your work items, and an observable collection to signal the UI:

```
public class TaskRunner<T>
{
    private readonly Queue<WorkItem<T>> _queue;

    public ObservableCollection<WorkItem<T>> NeedsAttention { get; private set; }

    public bool WorkRemaining
    {
        get { return NeedsAttention.Count > 0 && _queue.Count > 0; }
    }

    public TaskRunner(IEnumerable<WorkItem<T>> items)
    {
        _queue = new Queue<WorkItem<T>>(items);
        NeedsAttention = new ObservableCollection<WorkItem<T>>();
    }

    public event EventHandler WorkCompleted;

    public void LongRunningTask()
    {
        while (WorkRemaining)
        {
            if (_queue.Any())
            {
                var workItem = _queue.Dequeue();

                if (workItem.Validate())
                {
                    workItem.Action(workItem.Data);
                }
                else
                {
                    NeedsAttention.Add(workItem);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Thread.Sleep(500); // check if the queue has items every 500ms
            }
        }

        var completedEvent = WorkCompleted;
        if (completedEvent != null)
        {
            completedEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    public void Queue(WorkItem<T> item)
    {
        // TODO remove the item from the NeedsAttention collection
        _queue.Enqueue(item);
    }
}
```

Your UI codebehind could look something like

```
public class TaskRunnerPage : Page
{
    private TaskRunner<XElement> _taskrunner;

    public void DoWork()
    {
        var work = Enumerable.Empty<WorkItem<XElement>>(); // TODO create your workItems

        _taskrunner = new TaskRunner<XElement>(work);

        _taskrunner.NeedsAttention.CollectionChanged += OnItemNeedsAttention;

        Task.Run(() => _taskrunner.LongRunningTask()); // run this on a non-UI thread
    }

    private void OnItemNeedsAttention(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // e.NewItems contains items that need attention.
        foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
        {
            var workItem = (WorkItem<XElement>) item;
            // do something with workItem
            PromptUser();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// TODO Use this callback from your UI
    /// </summary>
    private void OnUserAction()
    {
        // TODO create a new workItem with your changed parameters
        var workItem = new WorkItem<XElement>();
        _taskrunner.Queue(workItem);
    }
}
```

This code is untested! But the basic principle should work for you.

Comment: This looks quite elegant, but I fear it'd raise more problems. If using this idea, I could simply call the Tasks from the mainthread as well. Probably it would also be a problem, if one task is relying on the information of another task, that is in the "NeedsAttention" state.

Comment: Yeah, definitely. The tasks need to be totally isolated from each other for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically to your case

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        var a = Test1("a");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        var b = (string)Invoke(new Func<string>(() => Test2("b")));
        MessageBox.Show(a + b);
    }

    private string Test1(string text)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
            return (string)this.Invoke(new Func<string>(() => Test1(text)));
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(text);
            return "test1";
        }
    }

    private string Test2(string text)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(text);
        return "test2";
    }
```

`Test2` is a normal method which you have to *invoke* from background worker. `Test1` can be called directly and uses safe pattern to invoke itself.

`MessageBox.Show` is similar to `yourForm.ShowDialog` (both are modal), you pass parameters to it (`text`) and you return value (can be a value of property of `yourForm` which is set when form is closed). I am using `string`, but it can be any data type obviously.